# AzureDevOps - YML - How to use deployment job output variable with VM resource

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a environment with two VMs, tagges with "SQL" and "APP", I would like to have deployment job targeting SQL vm and having step, creating a output variable, another deployment job targeting "APP" VM should able to consume it in its step

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried to achieve your solution? It is expected of askers to show research efforts.

Answer (score 3):

[Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables)

Job consuming the variable should use syntax like -

```
$[dependencies.<job-name>.outputs['<lifecycle-hookname>_<resource-name>.<step-name>.<variable-name>']]
```

Consider a scenario you have environment with name "env-vm"

env-vm has two vms registered with it, vm1 with tag SQL and vm2 with tag APP. refer below sample for how to produce and consume the output variable from deployment job

```
jobs:
- deployment: producer
  environment:
    name: env-vm
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: SQL
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the deployment variable value"
          name: setvarStep
        - script: echo $(setvarStep.myOutputVar)
          name: echovar

- deployment: consumer_deploy
  dependsOn: producer
  variables:
    myVarFromDeploymentJob: $[ coalesce(dependencies.producer.outputs['deploy_Vm1.setvarStep.myOutputVar'], 'fubar') ]
  environment: 
    name: env-vm
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: APP
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: "echo $(myVarFromDeploymentJob)"
          name: echovar
```